# As a Bitcoin Trader, what tools are available to execute trades?

Tags: trading

Looking to expand beyond using bitstamp and gox's (ok, well, that one was easy) built-in trading interfaces to something more unified and manageable. RTBTC seems to have a clean interface. What about alerts sent out when a certain price is reached? Are there any tools that track transactions for tax purposes?

Answer (score 1):

[CrypTrader](https://cryptrader.com/) is a website that unifies the exchanges via your API keys, so that you can trade all on one platform.

[MyBitAlert](http://www.mybitalert.com/) lets you set up email alerts when the price reaches a certain level.

[CoinReporting](http://www.coinreporting.com/) lets you enter your trades (or import them automatically) and show your P&L, and can even export trades for your tax declaration.